# Empty Pages by using ImportPage in script

Tags: scribus

I am trying to import pages in Scribus 1.5.5 from a Scribus Document with a script by using:

```
scribus.importPage("fromDoc", (2,3))
```

The script Imports just empty pages.
When I use the dropdown Menu  "Page->Import" it Imports also the text and image frames.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already replied to the [same question in the Scribus forums](http://forums.scribus.net/index.php/topic,3508.msg16546.html#msg16546)

With the current Scribus code I've tried:

```py
importPage('/tmp/lines.sla', (1,))
```

and it did import page 1 of `/tmp/lines.sla` as a new page in my current document.

In your question, it is unknown what is "fromDoc" and if the document you're reading from has three pages.

Comment: Thanks! I havent wrote the whole directory, that was the mistake. "fromDoc" is the filename, adopted from the scribus API. But I can't manipulate the objects from the imported pages. Is this normal?

Comment: do you have a snippet that fails so that i can try? you should probably post a new question with that snippet so that future people can easily find the answers...

Comment: btw, i thought that it could be an issue with the way you were writing the argumets... that's why i posted the full command...